# ¿Como no cargar los mismos personajes en cada escena?

Tags: unity3d

Mi problema es que dispongo de 60 personajes para un juego y no quiero y también no se si es necesario tener que cargar esos 60 personajes  en mis 10 escenas.

Lo que tengo en mente es que si se pueden crear en un lugar determinado del terreno de cada escena y con modificaciones determinadas como el tamaño, sus animaciones de ataque y movimiento, todo desde código  o si existe otra manera.

Comment: Abraham, no está claro la parte "dispongo de 60 personajes para un juego y no quiero" .

Comment: En si lo que pregunto es que tengo 60 personajes y no se si se tienen que declarar cada uno en cada escena y ademas no quiero tener que declararlo en cada escena porque se ve algo pesado. Gracias

Comment: Si las 10 escenas utilizan los 60 personajes al mismo tiempo, lo mejor es que los tengas ya cargados. ¿Es eso a lo que te refieres?

Comment: No solo cada jugador va usar 3 personajes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para cargarlos según necesites, debes tener los personajes en una carpeta llamada "Resources" e instanciarlos en tiempo de ejecución según tu necesidad:

```
GameObject myplayer= Instantiate(Resources.Load("personaje01", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
```

Comment: Gracias amigo por su apoyo.